# Lambda function receiving null S3 event object via SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm trying to invoke a Lambda function using an SNS event carrying an S3 event payload (i.e. S3 Put -> triggers an event published to an SNS topic -> delivers to a subscribed Lambda function), but it seems the only way I have been able to get to the actual S3 event information is to access it as a JsonNode and I know there has to be a better (e.g. deserialization).

I really thought I could have my Lambda function accept an S3EventNotification, due to the comments I found here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/event/S3EventNotification.java

> A helper class that represents a strongly typed S3 EventNotification item sent
>   to SQS, SNS, or Lambda.

So, how do I receive the S3EventNotification as a POJO?

Below are the various ways I have tried:

```
public class LambdaFunction implements RequestHandler<S3EventNotification, Object>{

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(S3EventNotification input, Context context) {
        System.out.println(JsonUtil.MAPPER.writeValueAsString(input));       
        return null;
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "awsRegion": null,
            "eventName": null,
            "eventSource": null,
            "eventTime": null,
            "eventVersion": null,
            "requestParameters": null,
            "responseElements": null,
            "s3": null,
            "userIdentity": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried the following (note: JsonUtil.MAPPER just returns a Jackson ObjectMapper):

```
public class LambdaFunction {
    public Object handleRequest(S3EventNotification records, Context context) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(JsonUtil.MAPPER.writeValueAsString(records));           
        return null;
    }
}
```

This returns the same as before:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "awsRegion": null,
      "eventName": null,
      "eventSource": null,
      "eventTime": null,
      "eventVersion": null,
      "requestParameters": null,
      "responseElements": null,
      "s3": null,
      "userIdentity": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I can access the S3 event payload by simply receiving the SNSEvent, however when I try to deserialize the msg payload into the S3EventRecord or S3EventNotification, there are differences in fields.  I really don't want to have to walk down the JsonNode manually...

```
public class LambdaFunction {
    public Object handleRequest(SNSEvent input, Context context) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Records: " + JsonUtil.MAPPER.writeValueAsString(input));

    for (SNSEvent.SNSRecord record : input.getRecords()) {
        System.out.println("Record Direct: " + record.getSNS().getMessage());
        JsonNode node = JsonUtil.MAPPER.readTree(record.getSNS().getMessage());
        JsonNode recordNode = ((ArrayNode) node.get("Records")).get(0);
        System.out.println(recordNode.toString());
        S3EventNotification s3events = JsonUtil.MAPPER.readValue(record.getSNS().getMessage(), new TypeReference<S3EventNotification>() {});
        System.out.println(s3events == null);

    }
    return null;
}
```

This returns the following:

```
{
  "eventVersion": "2.0",
  "eventSource": "aws:s3",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
  "eventTime": "2017-03-04T05:34:25.149Z",
  "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
  "userIdentity": {
    "principalId": "AWS:XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "requestParameters": {
    "sourceIPAddress": "<<IP ADDRESS>>"
  },
  "responseElements": {
    "x-amz-request-id": "XXXXXXXX",
    "x-amz-id-2": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX="
  },
  "s3": {
    "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "configurationId": "NotifyNewRawArticle",
    "bucket": {
      "name": "MYBUCKET",
      "ownerIdentity": {
        "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET"
    },
    "object": {
      "key": "news\/test",
      "size": 0,
      "eTag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
      "sequencer": "0058BA51E113A948C3"
    }
  }
}

Unrecognized field "sequencer" (class com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3ObjectEntity), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "size", "versionId", "eTag", "key"])
```

I am depending on aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.77 and aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.77.

Answer (score 4):

you should handle the SNSEvent instead of S3Event since the lambda consume your SNS events. below code works for me.

```
public Object handleRequest(SNSEvent request, Context context) {
    request.getRecords().forEach(snsRecord -> {
        System.out.println("Record Direct: " +snsRecord.getSNS().getMessage());
        S3EventNotification s3eventNotifcation=S3Event.parseJson(snsRecord.getSNS().getMessage());
        System.out.println(s3eventNotifcation.toJson());
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: It's pretty clear from printing out the SNSMessage that it holds a serialized S3Event object.  Regardless, I was trying to get it deserialized into a POJO and since it's supposed to match the S3Event, I thought that should work, however it's not for the reasons I outlined above.

Comment: your first lambada function lead to the conclusion, actually i just made the mistaken 2 days ago.  above code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but @Jin Wang answer didn't work for me.
Both `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Event`
And `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event`
did not have parseJson method.

The key to my solution is to understand the structure of the S3Event embedded inside the SNSEvent.

The message in SNS will look like

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "eu-west-2",
      "eventTime": "2023-07-24T12:34:17.747Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "12.34.56.78"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "CSPRCYNWCRX7KP9W",
        "x-amz-id-2": "whatEver"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "topic-20230718074429604200000001",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "source-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "PRINCIPLEID"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "Directory/File.txt",
          "size": 28,
          "eTag": "eeeeeeeeeeee",
          "sequencer": "0064BE6FC9AC89FC94"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is mapped to the structure of `com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification`

So the code will look similar to the one below

```
public Void handleRequest(SNSEvent request, Context context) {
        for (var snsRecord : snsEvent.getRecords()) {
            var s3Message = snsRecord.getSNS().getMessage();
            try {
                var s3Events = mapper.readValue(s3Message, S3EventNotification.class);
                var s3Event = s3Events.getRecords().get(0);
                var s3Bucket = s3Event.getS3().getBucket().getName();
                var s3key = s3Event.getS3().getObject().getKey();
                var s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3Bucket, s3key));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                System.out.println();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                RunTimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

We assume we have only one notification in the records list